# Build on launchpad with newer compiler

Tags: apt, compiling, ppa, launchpad

I've got a project I'd like to have built by launchpad recipe, but it requires C++14 support available in g++-5.1 or newer.

This compiler is easy to get on 14.04 LTS with the toolchain-r ppa, but I can't find any details on how to specify a required ppa in a launchpad project.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to specify one or more ppa-s that are required to build a recipe?  Is it even possible to get launchpad to host and build such a project?

Comment: https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/BuildingASourcePackage#Depending_on_other_PPAs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recipe is built in a PPA, shown under "Daily build archive" on the recipe page.  Assuming that it won't disrupt other builds in the same PPA, you can visit that PPA and select "Edit PPA dependencies" to add additional PPAs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the normal way doesn't work in your `control` file for `Build-Depends`.

```
Build-Depends: g++ (>= 5.1.0)
```

But you could use `g++-5.1`

```
Build-Depends: g++-5.1
```

But this more like a cheat and will fail on all systems with `g++` newer than 5.1.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: This is only true if the gcc-defaults source package in the archive in question hasn't been updated to point to 5.1.